# При публикации моей новости в контакте, база vk делает запись каждому моему подписчику? А если их 1000 или 10000?

Tags: база-данных, вконтакте, big-data

У пользователя есть новостная лента, где он видит новый контент от друзей и пабликов, мне интересно знать как сохраняется и выдается такая лента, самое первое что приходит на на ум как такое должно быть реализовано:
Есть база данных, в ней лежит массив новостных JSON строк, этот массив строк пополняется следующим образом, я публикую новость, и это новость записывается в массив новостных строк всем моим друзьям и подписчикам, и получается что если у меня 1000 друзей и подписчиков, то каждый раз когда я публикую новость, база данных должна делать 1000 записей. 
Все так и происходит? или там умнее все сделано?

Comment: Скорей всего ваша новость только вам в ленту сохраняется в бд.

Comment: А как тогда моя новость попадает в новостную ленту моих друзей и подписчиков?

Comment: Запросом к базе данных вытаскивают N новостей, которые были опубликованы группами/людьми, на которых они подписаны + оптимизировано всё это как-то. А сохраняют новость 1 раз. Зачем больше? Сами подумайте, если у вас 5 миллионов подписчиков, думаете возможно делать 5 миллионов записей в БД на каждую новость?

Comment: Выборкой из бд - берем все новости, у которых автор входит в мои друзья и показываем.

Comment: Это получается контакт при каждом заходе юзером во вкладку новости, из 100 млн пользователей, находит 1000 друзей + паблики и из их массива новостей вытаскивает свежий подмоссив, складывает 1000 подмассивов в новостную ленту пользователя, плюс выстраивает её иерархически по дате?

Comment: По моему вы смотрите со стороны NoSQL решений, т.е. нереляционных БД. А такие вещи в реляционке как то проще хранить. Новость сохраняется один раз. Когда какой то пользователь открывает страницу новостей то идет выборка свежих записей по его друзьям. Сборка таких данных в реляционной БД отрабатывает моментально (при правильно построенных индексах). И никаких массивов. Обычные записи реляционной БД